# <br/> is stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am sending a mail with the selected checkbox items in  emailbody. I wanted a line break after each checked items. I get a line break which i needed in email body but my problem is while it is stored in database, it is storing with `br` for example:

```
apple <br>orange <br>
```

So is there a way to give line break without br being stored in the database?

```
protected void check1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < check1.Items.Count ;i++ )
    {
        if (check1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
             comment.Text = "\u2022 " + check1.Items[i].Text + "<br/>" + comment.Text;        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's the HTML "line break" (<br />) or a text-based line break (\r\n etc), which one do you want/not want?

Comment: What do you mean stored in the database?  Are you storing your html based email body in the database?

Comment: If its not stored, how would you know that is where the line break is?

Comment: What's wrong with storing `<br>` in the database?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what exactly you are trying to do.  Do you email out then store? Why can't you store the br? Do you use the stored text again after?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fundamental issue is:

```
comment.Text = "\u2022 " + check1.Items[i].Text + "<br/>" + comment.Text;
```

Each time the selected item changes the *new* selected item(s) text (`Items[i].Text`) is added to the *old* selected item text (`comment.Text`) .. the more time the selection event occurs, the more item texts will be prepended!

I suspect that just the *last* selected values should be saved .. in any case, removing that "<br>" there would "keep it from being saved".

Comment: yes i am storing html based emailbody in the database.that is whatever user selects from the checkbox and writes in the comment box.i tried \r\n and environment.newline but its not working in my code except for br